# Binding a port for client tcp socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I have a problem about 'binging a local port for a client tcp socket'.
The code is as below:

```
void tcpv4_cli_connect(const char *srvhost, in_port_t srvport,
                       const char *clihost, in_port_t cliport)
{
    struct sockaddr_in srvaddr, cliaddr;
    struct in_addr     inaddr;
    int sockfd;

    bzero(&srvaddr, sizeof(srvaddr));
    inet_aton(srvhost, &inaddr);
    srvaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srvaddr.sin_addr   = inaddr;
    srvaddr.sin_port   = htons(srvport);

    bzero(&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));
    inet_aton(clihost, &inaddr);
    cliaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    cliaddr.sin_addr   = inaddr;
    cliaddr.sin_port   = htons(cliport);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &srvaddr, sizeof(srvaddr)) != 0)
        perror("Something Wrong");
    return;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    // Wrong for "220.181.111.86", but ok for "127.0.0.1"
    tcpv4_cli_connect("220.181.111.86", 80, "127.0.0.1", 40888);
    return 0;
}
```

When I do `tcpv4_cli_connect("220.181.111.86", 80, "127.0.0.1", 40888)` in main function, (220.181.111.86 is an address on Internet), an error will show up: **Something Wrong: Invalid argument**.

And if I comment `bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr))` in the code, things will be fine and a random port is used for client socket.

But it is alright when I do `tcpv4_cli_connect("127.0.0.1", 80, "127.0.0.1", 40888)` whether or not binding a port to client socket.

What does *Invalid argument* mean for a connect operation? I wonder if it is only allowed to bind a specific port for the client to connect to local address? Clients can only use random port to connect to a external server?
Is there someting I misunderstood?

/br
Ruan

Comment: Check what (if any) error `bind` returns.

Comment: Also, can you please explain *why* you want to bind the local address? And are you sure there's a route from the localhost interface to the server you want to connect to? Have you tried binding to the external interface instead?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, ah, you enlighten me, I should not have bound it to a loopback address which can not go for Internet address, what a stupid mistake.

Comment: You shouldn't have bound it at all. It isn't necessary in a client, unless it's misconfigured.

Comment: @EJP: sometimes it is necessary to bind locally, if the machine is connected to multiple networks at the same time and you need to specify which particular network the client should use when connecting to the server.

Answer (score 3):

When you `bind()` to `127.0.0.1` (`INADDR_LOOPBACK`), you are binding to a loopback interface that does not have access to the outside world, only to itself, so you cannot `connect()` to any IP other than `127.0.0.1`.  If you want to `bind()` to a local interface when you `connect()` to an outside server, you have to bind to the actual IP of an interface that is connected to a network that can reach that server.

If all you want to do is `bind()` to a specific port, but allow the OS to pick an appropriate interface for you, then bind to `0.0.0.0` (`INADDR_ANY`) instead.