# Send request not through VPN

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, vpn

I am trying to send a request in C# bypassing an active VPN (PPTP) connection. I am trying to specify my usual internet interface, not the VPN one, for this request.

How can I make a request through my usual ISP and not through the VPN in C#? I need to find out my IP assigned to me by my internet provider while I am connected to a VPN. This can be done with a request to icanhazip.com, but it will return my VPN IP when I need my ISP external IP.

The code below throws this exception:

> A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. 147.75.47.199:80.

```cs
//192.168.0.103 is my “usual internet” interface
string ipString = "192.168.0.103";
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipString);
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 0);

string host = "www.icanhazip.com";

string request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + host + "\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n";
byte[] encodedRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);

int bufferSize = 10000;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Bind(localEndPoint);
socket.Connect(host, 80); //throws exception here;
socket.Send(encodedRequest);
socket.Receive(buffer, 0, bufferSize, 0);

string decodedResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding a port for client tcp socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477775/binding-a-port-for-client-tcp-socket)

Comment: Check your routes with `netstat /r` and see if you still have one for your network adapter while being connected to the VPN.